# Upstart - handling stop when the process is killed

Tags: 14.04, upstart

I have upstart configuration for my java process:

**/etc/init/myjar.conf**

```
description "my jar"
author "me"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on shutdown

expect fork

script
    chdir /opt/myjar/
    java -jar myjar.jar >/var/log/myjar/myjar.log 2>&1
end script

post-start script
    emit myjar-local_running
end script
```

The service works fine, apart from the following scenario:

1. process is killed from outside, i.e: `killall java`
2. trying to stop the service: `sudo service myjar stop` <--- hanging......

The process is in the following state:

```
myjar start/killed, process 123
```

Can't restart it either...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated, but general suggestions: Use a `chdir` stanza instead of doing a `cd` in the `script` stanza, and use a `post-start script` stanza to emit the signal instead of using the main `script` stanza.

Comment: Possibly related: Are you sure the process forks? If so, does it fork exactly once? Could you try with `expect daemon`?

Comment: @muru, java doesn't fork, it starts a Java application calling main method of class in myjar.jar

Comment: @Letizia that's what I thought, but since OP added an `expect` line, which should only be used if the process forks, I figured something odd might be happening. And since `expect` should cause it to hang on `start` if it forked too few times, I think it actually is forking.

Comment: @muru changed to use `chdir` and `post-start scrip` stanza. Tried with `expect daemon`, still the same behavior.

Comment: @Godsaur And without an `expect` line at all? (The `chdir` line goes above the `script` line, btw.)

Comment: @muru, may be the problem is `cd` command as reported in comment 5 of this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/upstart/+bug/406397)

Comment: @muru removing expect fixes the issue!

Comment: @Letizia I think you're spot on, given that removing the expect now fixes the issued. I suspect OP had to use `expect` since the extra commands in the `script` stanza confused Upstart's tracking of PIDs and so cleaning up the script and removing the expect fixed it. Could you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @muru, Thank you for your honesty, but would not be a problem if you wrote an answer using my comments. I addressed to you my comments because I wanted to share the information in order to find the solution quickly... I was going to sleep :)

Comment: @Godsaur I don't know if you have changed the job other than removing `expect`, but this is what I had in mind: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8732327/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to upstart manual [expect fork](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#expect-fork):

```
   Upstart will expect the process executed to call fork(2) exactly once.
```

and according to [comment 5](https://bugs.launchpad.net/upstart/+bug/406397/comments/5) in [init: job stuck with expect fork/daemon when parent reaps child](https://bugs.launchpad.net/upstart/+bug/406397) bug:

> when you use "expect fork" or "expect daemon" combined with "script",
>   Upstart ends up following the first spawned child whose exit status is
>   reaped by the shell.

In your case, `upstart` probably follows `chdir` pid.

Your `upstart` script seems a task job because neither `chdir` nor `java` command fork,
so, removing `expect fork` should fix the issue.